# how to add image on navigation bar

Tags: ios

Hi guys I am new to iOS programming and i'm currently doing a project that will look like you have an image on your navigation bar, and that will be on the maximum of four then the image will serve as a life and every wrong move will decrease by one.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to develop some sort of game then generally you wouldn't want a navigation bar. Navigation bars are mostly used for two buttons and a title.

Something to look into would be using container views. You can have your game on one container and then your images on another container view. You can just have 4 images and when they make a wrong move you can just change the image.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to add an image.

> To add a customView

```
var image = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35))
  var barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: image)
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

> Another way,

```
   let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "image"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "someAction")

  navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [button] //you can add more than one buttons
```